# how to color HTML rows?

Tags: python, html

I have the following code where I construct HTML rows,now when key is present in dict1 I want to color the row and when key is present in dict2 another color?
how can I modify this code to color the rows?

```
for item in jiradb :
    MailBody = MailBody + "<tr>"
    MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + str(icount) + "</td>"
    print get_field(item, 'key')
    key = item['key']
    key_after_none_check = get_field(item,'key');
    crashid_link = "https://company.com/data/browse/" + key;
    key_present_in_anr_tombstone = False;
    if ((key in dict1) and (dict1[key] !=0)):
        key_present_in_anr_tombstone = True
        #MailBody "<a href=\"" + crashid_link + "\">" + str(get_field(item,'key ')) + "</a>;
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + "<a href=\"" + crashid_link + "\">" + str(key_after_none_check) + "</a>" + "(" + "x" + str(dict1[key]) + ")" +  "</td>"
    if ((key in dict2) and (dict2[key] !=0)):
        key_present_in_anr_tombstone = True
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + "<a href=\"" + crashid_link + "\">" + str(key_after_none_check) + "</a>" + "(" + "x" + str(dict2[key]) + ")" +  "</td>"
    if key_present_in_anr_tombstone == False:
        MailBody = MailBody + "<td>" + "<a href=\"" + crashid_link + "\">" + str(key_after_none_check) + "</a>" + "</td>"
    MailBody = MailBody + "<td style=\"width:100%\">" + get_field(item,'summary') + "</td>"
    MailBody = MailBody + "<td style=\"width:100%\">" + get_field(item,'Resolution') + "</td>"
    icount = icount + 1

MailBody = MailBody + "</tr>"
```

Comment: Just a side note -- You'd probably find that working with this code is a lot easier if you'd adopt a templating system (e.g. `jinja2`).

Comment: will try that for next project,kind of difficult to move to jinja2 now unless you prove otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, try to fetch the values first, and use css styling to color the rows.

```
rows = []
for item in jiradb:
  data = []
  key = item['key']
  dict1_value = dict1.get(key)
  dict2_value = dict2.get(key)
  key_after_none_check = get_field(item,'key')
  crashid_link = "https://company.com/data/browse/{}".format(key)

  row = '<td><span style="background-color:{};"><a href="{}">{}</a>(x{})</span></td>'
  color = 'white' # default color

  if dict1_value != None:
    color = 'red';
    data.append(row.format(color, crashid_link, key_after_none_check, dict1_value))
  if dict2_value != None:
    color = 'blue'
    data.append(row.format(color, crashid_link, key_after_none_check, dict2_value))

  if not dict1_value and not dict2_value:
    data.append('<td><a href="{}">{}</a></td>'.format(crashid_link, key_after_none_check))

  data.append('<td style="width:100%">{}</td>'.format(get_field(item, 'summary')))
  data.append('<td style="width:100%">{}</td>'.format(get_field(item, 'Resolution')))
  rows.append(data)

mail_rows = []
for count,row in enumerate(rows):
  head = '<tr><td>{}</td></tr>'.format(count+1)
  body = '\n'.join(row)
  footer = '</tr>'
  mail_rows.append('{}{}{}'.format(head,body,footer))

mail_body = ''.join(mail_rows)
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

[image: rows]

Comment: Burhan - why does `for count,row in enumerate(data)` loop only 5 times(0..4),am using python 2.7

Comment: does this code work at your end?I tried printing data and it has the data appended correctly,Its not clear to me why `for count,row in enumerate(data) loop only 5 times(0..4)`

Comment: There was a small typo, `enumerate(data)` should be `enumerate(rows)`

Comment: there are 2 other mistakes,1.`if dict1_value != 0:` should be `if dict1_value != None:` ,same applies for dict2. 2. rows get printed in a new line compared to the count and I cant figure out how to fix it , count and row should be in the same row ,do you know?

Comment: I added screen shot of the table,as you can see the count and the row data are not aligned

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite a tangled mess.  I'm not sure if I got it all right, but take a look at this version.  I don't know where icount comes from, but you can get it from enumerate.  I made a string to contain what I think is a template for your table rows.  Then I took out all the repetitive logic in the if clauses.  Collected the values, and then popped them into the template.

```
for icount, item in enumerate(jiradb) :
    vars = []
    MailBody = MailBody + 
        """<tr><td>{0}</td>
           <td><a href="https://company.com/data/browse/{1}">{2}</a>(x{3})</td>
           <td style='width:100%'>{4}</td>
           <td style='width:100%'>{5}</td></tr>
        """
    vars.append(icount+1)

    key = item['key']
    vars.append(key)
    key_after_none_check = get_field(item,'key');
    vars.append(key_after_none_check)
    key_present_in_anr_tombstone = False;

    if ((key in dict1) and (dict1[key] !=0)):
        key_present_in_anr_tombstone = True
        vars.append(dict1[key])

    if ((key in dict2) and (dict2[key] !=0)):
        key_present_in_anr_tombstone = True
        vars.append(dict2[key])

    if key_present_in_anr_tombstone == False:
        vars.append(key_after_non_check)

    vars.append(get_field(item, 'summary'))
    vars.append(get_field(item, 'Resolution'))

    MailBody.format(*vars)
```